# Fixing image position in latex, [h] doesn't work

Tags: latex

Here's the usual code

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{ncurve.jpg}
\caption{tata}
\label{fig:ts}
\end{figure}
```

including the float package

But the result is the image at any other place, followed by [H]. What's happening?

Comment: This should not be the case. Perhaps you're including conflicting packages... can you provide a minimal example that replicates this (faulty) behaviour? It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You could try `\begin{figure}[h!]`.

Answer (score 6):

i have the same problem so i have simply fix it by using flot package

```
\usepackage{float}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, but I added the command [h] next to the {figure}

```
\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.70\textwidth]{image/image} 
  \caption{image example}
  \label{fig-clean-architecture}
\end{figure}
```

and it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

The **H** option should always place the element at the correct position (include the `float` package before usage):

```latex
\usepackage{float}

...

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{IMAGE}
  \caption{CAPTION}
  \label{fig:LABEL}
\end{figure}
```

Based on [this](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_images_and_tables).